# removing leading spaces and replacing multiple spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a lot of buttons in a certain program. But none of the buttons have specific classes. Therefore I add them via the below code.

```
jQuery('.btn').each(function() {
  var btnFullText = jQuery(this).text();
  var btnText = btnFullText.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  jQuery(this).addClass(btnText);
});
```

So far this works very nicely. But as you might have guessed not perfectly.

Some buttons are coded like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('taskform.add');"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> New Task</a>
```

Which creates a class like this `-new-task` because there is a space in the link:

1. How can I adapt the code above to just remove all spaces before the first word.
2. How can I make sure that if between words there are multiple spaces this becomes only one `-`.

So all example links below return `new-task`

```
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> New Task</a>
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>     New     Task</a>
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>         New    Task</a>
```

PS1: I need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in this case.

PS2: Above code can be altered to be fully Javascript/jQuery if you wish.

PS3: I cannot change the links in the program.

PS4: I would love to hear better suggestions for the title.

**The Code So Far With Help From The Comments Below**

```
  jQuery('.btn').each(function() {
    var btnFullText = jQuery(this).text();
    var btnTrimmedText = btnFullText.trimLeft().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var btnText = btnTrimmedText.replace(/-+/, '-');
    jQuery(this).addClass(btnText);
  });
```

Comment: Did you look up "left trim JavaScript"

Comment: @epascarello No not at all for the simple reason I don't know all these terms. So I don't just go looking them up. But I just did due to your comment. So thank you very much for that. Am I correctly assuming that I have to left trim before I do the replace?

Comment: You could `trim()` the value, then replace spaces with `-` and then replace any occurance of `-+` with just `-` to get rid of the duplicates

Comment: @purple11111 Yes.

Comment: @epascarello Your suggestion for left trim worked brilliantly. Thank you very much. My assumption to do it before the replace was correct.

Comment: @Taplar I don't understand what you have written. I am so sorry. I don't understand the `-+` part?

Comment: `replace(/-+/, '-')` for the cases that 'New-----Task' were the result.

Comment: @Taplar I am sure you know code a whole lot better then I do but does the `+` mean `----` as well as `---------------------`

Comment: Or I guess if you're replace of spaces matched multiple spaces with a single '-' replace you wouldn't need that secondary replace.  Yes, `+` in a regex means 1 or more.

Comment: @Taplar What if a word is followed by a dash and a space? It would cause a `--`.

Comment: @Taplar If only I could understand these items put into the replace a lot better then it would be such a lot easier. :-) but that is my struggle. Thanks to everyone for helping me out on this!

Comment: @ChinLeung has a valid point.  Would it be a valid solution in that case to have two dashes?

Comment: @Taplar I don't think it is a major issue just looking strange. I want those classes so I can force click events and CSS. In such cases I just need to add `--` to the classname but if at all possible to make it into `-` a single then that would be preferred as it would be just better. Asthetic and code wise I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //get the text
    //trim the leading and trailing spaces
    //replace all occurances of one or more spaces with '-'
    //lowercase the result
    var clazz = $this.text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    
    //only do this if you don't want '--' in your ids
    clazz = clazz.replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');
    
    $this.addClass(clazz);
    console.log(clazz);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> New Task</a>
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>     New     Task</a>
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>         New    Task</a>
<a><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>         New  -  Task</a>
```

Comment: I am completely confussed by ID. The question was about classes. So am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that after I submitted it.  Changed to class.

Comment: you made this `.edit form fieldset .btn-toolbar .btn-group .btn.btn-info:not(.dropdown-toggle)` become `.save` which is so much better!!!. Thank you very much. If possible could you give me advise on how to make the question better?

Comment: What do you mean make the question better?  I think we got the gist of what you were after.  Questions about what to do with '--' were more just outliers people think of while reading a question.

Comment: You stated what you were after.  You gave an example of the markup, and you provided the logic that you were currently trying to reach your goal.  Pretty solid start to a question.

Comment: Alright that is great news. Then hopefully lots of people benefit from it. I know I did from your great solution. Once again thank you very much!